# Morphism problem

Tags: group-theory

Let $p$, $l$ two prime numbers such that $l\mid p-1$. Let $\mathbb{P}$ a cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*}$ of order $l$ and $\mathbb{L}$ the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*}$ of order $\frac{p-1}{l}$.

Assuming that $l^2$ $\nmid$ $p-1$. I need to proof $\psi(\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*})=\mathbb{L}$ where
$\psi$ is the application:

$\psi:\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*}\to\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*}$, $x\mapsto x^l$.

I proof that $\psi(\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*})\subset \mathbb{L}$.
But I don't know how to proof  $\mathbb{L}\subset\psi(\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*})$.

I think problem can be resume like:
Let $y \in \mathbb{L}$, proof that it exists an $x\in \mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*}$ such that $y=x^l$

But I don't know how to proof it.

I also need to proof that $y$ have $l$ antecedents.
Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Are you not allowed to use the fact that the group you are working in is cyclic?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson my bad. We know that $\mathbb{L}$  is cyclic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement is true.

If $A$ is a finite abelian group and an integer $l$ is coprime to $|A|$,
then the mapping $\psi:A\rightarrow A$ given by the rule
$$
\psi(x)=x^l, x\in A,
$$
is an automorphism of the group $A$, in particular $\psi(A)=A$.

Proof. 1) $\psi$ is a homomorphism. Since $A$ is abelian, we have
$$
\psi(xy)=(xy)^l=x^ly^l=\psi(x)\psi(y).
$$

2. $\psi$ is  injective. If $\psi(x)=\psi(y)$, then $\psi(xy^{-1})=1$. Let
   $a=xy^{-1}$. Then $a^l=1$. Let $\operatorname{ord}(a)=s$. Then $s$ divides $l$
   and $|A|$. Since $l$ and $|A|$ are relatively prime, it follows that
   $s=1$. So $a=1$ and $x=y$.
3. $\psi$ is surjective. Since $A$ is finite and $\psi$ is injective, it
   follows that $\psi$ is surjective.

Comment: Yeah but in my case l divide |A|=p-1 then : $p=31$, $l=5$ $(p-1/l)=6$, $\mathbb{P}=<2>$ ,$\mathbb{L}=<6>$ $\psi:\mathbb{Z}_{31}^{*}  \to\mathbb{Z}_{31}^{*}$, $x\mapsto x^5$. $\psi$ is not injective : $\psi( \lbrace 1,2,4,8,16  \rbrace)=1$

Comment: In your case  $\psi(L)=L$.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand, you proof that $\psi(L)=L$ and since $\psi(L)\subset\psi(\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*})$ then $L\subset\psi(\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*})$  ? Finally $L=\psi(L)=\psi(\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*})$  How to proof for the application $\psi:\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*}\to\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*}$, $x\mapsto x^l$ that every image have $l$ antecedents ?

Comment: Answer to the first question. Yes, it is.
Here is the complete reasoning:
Since $l$ and $(p-1)/l$ are coprime,
$p-1=l\cdot(p-1)/l$, and $L\cap P=\{1\}$ it follows that
$\mathbb{Z}_p^*=L\cdot P$. Therefore,
$$
(\mathbb{Z}_p^*)^l=(L\cdot P)^l=L^l\cdot P^l=L^l\cdot\{1\}=L^l=L.
$$
I did not understand your second question. Sorry.